# setTimeout function in custom react hook gets invoked many times eventhough it is cleared before its time

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, settimeout

I have a react function component in which I want to track screen width in real time.

I wrote inside the component something like that:

```
export const HowItWorksSection: FC<HowItWorksSectionProps> = () => {
  const [screenWidth, setScreenWidth] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    let timer: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout> | null = null;

    const listener = () => {
      if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);

      timer = setTimeout(() => {
        setScreenWidth(window.innerWidth);
        console.log(screenWidth);
      }, 100);
    };

    window.addEventListener('resize', listener);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', listener);
    };
  }, [screenWidth]);
```

In such a above case it is working like a charm and I can use the screenWidth for displaying something conditionaly.

I wanted to extract the logic to custom react hook in order to re-use it. The code of my hook is below:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { setTimeout } from 'timers';

export const useDebounceScreenWidth = () => {
  const [screenWidth, setScreenWidth] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    let timer: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout> | null = null;

    const listener = () => {
      if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);

      timer = setTimeout(() => {
        setScreenWidth(window.innerWidth);
        console.log(screenWidth);
      }, 1000);
    };

    window.addEventListener('resize', listener);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', listener);
    };
  }, [screenWidth]);

  return [screenWidth];
};
```

Now in my component I want to make a use of it and here where it begins to work not as it supposed (1000 ms is placed in custom hook consciously too highlight the issue) :/ Below I showed how I make a use of that custom hook in my component:

```
export const HowItWorksSection: FC<HowItWorksSectionProps> = () => {
  const [screenWidth] = useDebounceScreenWidth();
```

Now everytime when I change the screen size my set time out function gets invoked as many times as timer was set eventhough everytime it was cleared before its time passed.

[Console screenshot where we can see how many times timeout function gets invoked per each screen width change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3Dn5.png)

Can anybody help me understand what I am doing wrong here ?? :(

Comment: I copy/pasted your code into a running codesandbox and it looks to function correctly. What is `import { setTimeout } from 'timers';` though? Maybe there's some issue in there?

Comment: Hi Drew ;) 

setTimeout is only for set the type of timer variable in typescript and it does not have any influence on how the whole function works. 

The whole code works returnining the window.innerHeight but not as it supposed to.

setTimeout purpose it to restrict the number of window.innerHeight invokes. When you change the screen width just once you should see only one window.innerHeight value in console but you see e.g. 678 na number on the lef side like 30 which means inner function was revoked 30 times during the drag where it should beonly once. Have you tried it in react env?

Comment: Think you could fork this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/settimeout-function-in-custom-react-hook-gets-invoked-many-times-eventhough-it-i-zn0bv) and break it and reproduce your issue?

Comment: I think I could do it ;)

Comment: Wow now I got lost and do not have the faintest idea why in my real life project it bahaves so strange and on isolated env in codesandbox it is working perfectly :/ Hmmm so the reason must be something else other that this piece of code and that is the one positive thing here :)
Anyway thank you for your time and help. Once I will finally find the root cause then I will share it here for sure ;)!

Comment: That was my suspicions as well, that once you got enough more of *your* code running in a codesandbox that it *might* trigger the bugginess. Good luck, and if you hit the issue in a sandbox feel free to ping (@) me in a comment here and I can take a look.